# Why does Blender constantly lose image sequence textures? Can I fix it?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, image, .exr

I am using the latest stable release and I have several images as planes in the scene with EXR image sequences, at some random point it just turns them purple so I have to relink those again and tweak from the scratch each time, that`s annoying and time consuming, can I do something to prevent it? I am mostly in EEvee if that is important.

Comment: try doing this in cycles, it might work.

Comment: maybe but it would take forever to do animation lol

Comment: Yes, but I will say that it should work with cycles. Or, you could take the frames, make a movie file out of them and use the image texture as a movie, though the choice is yours.